# how can I optimize docker and, when transpiling a React app, I get a commons.js (in cache) and an app.js

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, webpack-4

We are using Docker and React.

I would like to be able to have two separate lines in my Dockerfile. One that transpiles the vendor dependencies in, say, `common.js` and another one that transpiles the code that we write in, say, `app.js`

By doing so, I hope to leverage the caching functionalities of Docker and hence speed up the CI/CD

Comment: You can not have two  CMD at one Docker file. you should use entrypoint script for that purpose to do the both job at entrypoint level.

Comment: i edited my question: it is really just meant as Dockerfile steps. One step for `commons.js` and one for the rest. So I can cache the former